# Call a method in Python using Selenium and Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to scraping a website with Scrapy and I would like to call a method in a class. But the method is not called and strangely does not report error.
The method interested is parsequestion and is called by the parse function inside the for cycle. 
Thanks

```
class QuoraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quora"
    allowed_domains = ["quora.com"]
    BASE_URL = 'https://quora.com/'

def __init__(self):


    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\iaffa\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')

    self.start_urls = ["https://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming/all_questions"]

    print "Getting Answer"

    self.driver.get("http://www.quora.com/")
    #LOG IN

def parse(self, response)
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
    post_elems = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pagedlist_item")

    i=1
    url_list = []
    date_time_list = []

    for post in post_elems:

        Text = post.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"question_text")]').text
        url_list.append(post.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"question_link")]').get_attribute('href'))
        date_time_list.append(post.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"timestamp")]/a').text)


    uid =1
    for (url,date) in zip(url_list,date_time_list):
        self.parsequestion(uid,url,date) ##I can't call this function
        uid += 1


def parsequestion(self,uid,url,date): #the function that i want

    self.driver.get(url)


    #create item quest
    yield itemquest

    #create item ans
    yield itemans
```

Comment: Well, this is just a snippet of your class... so I cannot verify that the function is really in the same class... Perhaps showing the full class would help -- and if you could tell that the `for` loop is executed. Did you debug it?

Comment: I can not run debugging , because i run the spider from the command line .
However I am sure that the second function is in the same class.

However , can you tell me if Scrapy allows the call of other functions in addition to parse method?

Comment: Well, you can "debug" your application even if you start it from the command line: just put `print` statements inside the `for` loop and in the methods you are interested in. This is a wood-cutter but working solution for this task. I don't quite understand your other question but you can call other functions from your code of course -- and you can use `callbacks` for `yield` requests.

Comment: Sorry again . I modified the code to understand the problem better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the function is not being called? The function is probably called but you are not doing anything with the return value.

`parsequestion()` returns a generator. If you want `parse()` to return the items returned by `parsequestion()` in the end, you need to

```
yield self.parsequestion(uid,url,date)
```

instead.

Also, `itemquest` and `itemans` are not defined anywhere, so if this is the entire code then that will generate an error.